# pointing loginmodal to login view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this piece of code in my template and as you can see this line

```
<li><a href="#loginModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
```

I am interested in using it but i don't know how to point it to my login view to pull data from

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#loginModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am not an expert in bootstrap, I downloaded the template of bootstrap modal.I want to use the pop up effect that specific line gives me as result. I couldn't find anything online that could help that's why I am asking here thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need jquery to run bootstrap's modal.
In your < li > there's should be a line that says  data-target="#myModal", this calls the modal (or popup) named myModal

The code that calls the modal:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#loginModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

The modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

THe fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jennift/n57fk1c9/

Comment: Yea i saw that it was and the end of the file thanks and can you please tell where can i find code that allows me to like update a profile pic without refreshing the page

Comment: I don't think bootstrap has a feature like that, though you can try angularjs (or something similar) - all of which I'm not familiar -  or if you are just looking to automate browser refresh when a change to your code is made, you can try gulp/grunt.